# Three-tiered application in .net

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm currently studying MCPD at a local college facility and I have formed the bases that my lecturer knows little about his/her subject.

Here's the project we got from another lecturer in the area.

(It's in VS 2010 and via C#)

> Create a 3 tier application for facilitators to handle students/
>
> 1 (Create a DB) <---- This Is easy enough and actually made sense. Did this without a sweat
>
> 2 - Create a DataLayer - This must be a DataService
>
> 2.1 Add an .edmx model to your DataService that is generated from the database that you have created in step 1
>
> 2.2 Add the following Queryable service Operators:
>
> 2.2.1 GetStudent() - Lists all students from the Database
>
> <<<<-- AND 5 MORE Queries here-->>>>
>
> 2.3 - Give all Your clients Read rights only to all your entities.
>
> 2.4 - Give all your clients read/writes(Yep I quoted from the page) rights to all your service operations and student Entity.
>
> 2.5 - Configure your Service1.svc file to work with the System.Data.Services.DataServiceHostFactory
>
> 3 - Create a Wpf Application
>
> 3.1 Enable the Users to view Students, Qualifications and so forth based on their login.
>
> 3.2 Create functionality to allow facilitators to ad new Students using an xml file.
>
> 3.3 Must create an Add using xml or Add using text files window.

Now, my disclaimer : I'm absolutely no specialist or anything good. I have 4 years experience in WinForms with databases. So that's some very limited knowledge.

BUT: the limited knowledge I have.. tell me that nr 2. wants a web service or something of the latter and then not use it and rather use a WPF app to communicate to the DB.

Now as I am willing to insult the thought that has gone into this poorly thought out project, I am also willing to accept the fact, should I be wrong or not have understood correctly.

So now, can anyone please explain to me if this project is even feasible or savvy?

If so, I shall gladly accept reasoning and admit my failure.

Comment: This isn't really a constructive question, but: given what you posted, I see no implication that the WPF app *shouldn't* use the service and should instead hit the database directly... Hence, the three tiers are database, service, client. What's the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for in an answer? I'm reading through this and am not finding your question. I'm sorry that your Lecturer and his assignment are not up to your standards. Perhaps you should consider speaking with a counselor?

Comment: Like Dan J says in short: You need to make the WPF app talk to the Service, not the DB. Period.

Answer (score 2):

The description is totally confusing, but my assumption is you're supposed to create a model using EF, then wrap that in a WCF service then have the WPF app communicate with the Web Service.

Comment: Yes, I see now the gravity of doing this late at night. Nice. 

Well as stated I'll admit my failure. Thanx for pointing it out though. I really do appreciate it.

It was to my understanding that the services was used only for web based applications..hence why would I be needing a service if I could just connect to the DB itself? Yesterday I have done copious research on the matter before posting but it seems I didn't get that you could still connect a service to the WPF client.

Do you have any specific tips I may use when reattempting this project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see what is wrong here.

Basically you:

1. create a Database (meh)
2. create a DataLayer, i.e. a standalone class library containing objects describing every entity in your database (you can possibly use `NHibernate`/`EntityFramework` if you want to look cool, or you can simply create objects and define the database queries in separate methods, which just read in Database and returns the objects you defined in your DataLayer, but with details inside)
3. Create a WPF app which will use this DataLayer as a model, and show a GUI to allow users to browse students (ie. query Database for students, add/edit/delete their details...).

Again, this seems all very basic to me, unless I didn't understand it